# Assets and relative file paths

Tags: assets

I have an assets field type in a matrix cell. To place this on my page I am using

```
<img src="{cell_1}">
```

which gives the full url

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/image.jpeg">
```

That is great but is going to ping up as an insecure element on https pages. How would I get this on my page with a relative path to avoid that issue? I know I can use filename but hardcoding the path in the template isnt really an option.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
{assets_cell}
<img src="/images/{filename}" />
{/assets_cell}
```

That'll need to be in the channel entries tag, in your Matrix tag. The full list of variables is under "Primary Tag Pair" in our [Assets docs](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/docs/templates).  So you can build your paths "a la carte" if needed. :)

Comment: Also check your Upload Filedirs URL settings - if you have used absolute URL there and it is starting with http://, then you probably shouldn't be all that surprised :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure I know what you mean. Are you suggesting adding a new field in my matrix and writing that code in it?

oh I get it now. The problem is that I am not always going to know the path so wouldn't want to hard code it in the template.

Sorry scratch that, I didn't see the comment posted by Andris tucked away there :(

That was totally the problem, cheers Andris.